# resize multiple images on upload not working

Tags: php, file, upload, resize

I'm having a couple of issues when I try to resize temp files that are being uploaded.

I'm using the following **ResizeImage.php** class:

```
class ResizeImage {
    // *** Class variables
    private $image;
    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $imageResized;

    function __construct($fileName)
    {
        // *** Open up the file
        $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

        // *** Get width and height
        $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function openImage($file)
    {
        // *** Get extension
        $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

        switch($extension)
        {
            case '.jpg':
            case '.jpeg':
                $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                break;
            case '.gif':
                $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                break;
            case '.png':
                $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                break;
            default:
                $img = false;
                break;
        }
        return $img;
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    public function processImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
    {
        // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
        $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

        $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


        // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


        // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
        if ($option == 'crop') {
            $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
    {

       switch ($option)
        {
            case 'exact':
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                break;
            case 'portrait':
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                break;
            case 'landscape':
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                break;
            case 'auto':
                $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                break;
            case 'crop':
                $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                break;
        }
        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
    {
        $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
        $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
        return $newWidth;
    }

    private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
    {
        $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
        $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
        return $newHeight;
    }

    private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
    {
        if ($this->height < $this->width)
        // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
        {
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
        }
        elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
        // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
        {
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
        }
        else
        // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
        {
            if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            } else {
                // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            }
        }

        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
    {

        $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
        $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

        if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
            $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
        } else {
            $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
        }

        $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
        $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
    {
        // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
        $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
        $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

        $crop = $this->imageResized;
        //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

        // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
    {
        // *** Get extension
        $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
           $extension = strtolower($extension);

        switch($extension)
        {
            case '.jpg':
            case '.jpeg':
                if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                    imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                }
                break;

            case '.gif':
                if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                    imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                }
                break;

            case '.png':
                // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                     imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                }
                break;

            // ... etc

            default:
                // *** No extension - No save.
                break;
        }

        imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
    }


    ## --------------------------------------------------------

}
```

The class works great for files already on the server in a specific directory.
However if I try to use it for temp files that are being uploaded through a form like this:

```
$counter = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
if($counter > 0){

    for($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++) {

        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if($tmpFilePath != ""){

            $filePath = $path1.$path2.'/'.$path3.'/'.time().$i.'.jpg';

            $resizeObj = new ResizeImage($tmpFilePath);
            $resizeObj -> processImage(2000, 2000, 'auto');
            $resizeObj -> saveImage($filePath, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following PHP Warnings:

```
imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/ResizeImage.php on line 25
imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/ResizeImage.php on line 26
imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/ResizeImage.php on line 68
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You could remove the @ before the imagecreate functions to see why they fail

Comment: Relevant ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770795/php-temporary-file-upload-not-valid-image-resource

Comment: @deg yes it did help a ton. I just realized that temp files don't have an extension so the class constructor was calling the openImage() method which was testing for an extension of the file. I'll explain how I fixed it below

Comment: Yes, that is the detail I was pointing at. Lots of echo and print_r everywhere are your friends.

Comment: I wrote something a while back that might help you on your way https://github.com/bobrocha/imagebox/blob/master/app/includes/ImageFileUpload.php

Answer (score 0):

After checking the post @deg found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5770848/4484794)

I realized that the openImage() method was expecting an extension for the supplied file(s).
Since temp files don't have an extension a quick and dirty trick for me was to just read the temp file contents and create the image from string.

the openImage() function now looks like this:

```
private function openImage($file) {
    $image = file_get_contents($file);
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
    $return $img;
}
```

since I'm working only with jpeg files this works ok for me.
I guess additional testing could be done for the temp file types to cover the rest.